# I am trying to extract key values from a json file in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

How can I extract `hi`, `hi2`, `hi3` to a xlsx file in [jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) to be further used?

```
{
  "hi": {},
  "hi2": {},
  "hi3": {},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) which allows executing [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) queries and JMESPath has [`keys` function](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#keys)

So you will be able to get these `hi`, `hi2` and `hi3` as simple as:

```
keys(@)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: Hi, there i am trying to extract data from a json which was received as response from an earlier http sampler.Tried your method but getting an error...

Comment: Well, in this case as a workaround you can try using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with the following code: `new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).keySet().eachWithIndex { key, index -> vars.put('var_' + (index + 1), key) }`, it will create variables like `var_1`, `var_2`, etc. containing your response attribute names. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.